# What is the difference between finder and meta hook?

Tags: python, python-3.3

Here [import-hooks](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks) it is written that *meta hooks* are registered in `sys.meta_path`. Also in this list there are kept *finders*. So what is the difference between *meta hook* and *finder*? Are they the same thing? And why are they kept in the same place?

Answer (score 1):

The document you're quoting says:

> Meta hooks are registered by adding new finder objects to sys.meta_path

So, I'd say yes, they're the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

They are subtlety different. This [document](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) provides a thorough discussion of the import machinery.

Meta hooks are called at the start of import processing. As a result, they can become involved in all types of imports including imports such as builtin modules or frozen modules as well as the start of handling disk based module location via `sys.path`. Basically, at this level

Path hooks are invoked later in import processing during the processing of each `sys.path` entry. They have the opportunity to return an object that will take full responsibility for locating modules in that particular path entry. For example, if `sys.path` contains `[/usr/lib/Python3, /home/user/mypython]`, you could provide a path hook which would be able to do non-standard stuff to locate modules in your project `mypython`

Both hooks allow you to supply a `finder` which can take complete responsibility for locating modules in specific contexts. For example, a meta path hook is used to import modules from `zip` files.